# how to background-attachement: fixed to a div not viewport

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-attachment

I have a large background cover.

```
<div id="cover">
    ...
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#cover {
    background:url('cover.jpg') no-repeat fixed center center / cover;
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**The expected output** : The background image, resized to ***350px x 100%*** (in my case 350x900), should have a scroll effect based on the `<div id="cover"></div>`.

**The actual output** : The background image, resized to ***viewport*** (in my case 1440x900), has a scroll effect based on `<html></html>`.

What I want is for background-attachement:fixed to be relative to the div not the viewport.

Comment: That is not possible, `fixed` is always in regard to the viewport, that is how it is specified. Depending on what you actually want to achieve (not sure what you actually mean by _“What I want is for background-attachement:fixed to be relative to the div not the viewport”_) there might be workarounds.

Comment: I am looking for a 'parallax' effect from the fixed attachement (with pure CSS3). Something like the new Twitter cover effect. Oh and something NOT laggy as most of the parallax stuff out there.

Comment: Not really understanding what your asking here, but if you're looking for CSS only parallax you should check this out: http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter

Answer (score 1):

Background images are by default "fixed" to the element they are attached to. When you set a background CSS property to fixed, it does the same it would do for a DOM element, it makes it fixed regarding the whole document (viewport).

Changing the fixed property to scroll should do the trick here:

```
background:url('cover.jpg') no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
```